# Liferay Service Pack and Fixpack

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp, service-pack

Is latest service pack installed If I install latest fixpack? Currently I install latest fixpack, but i check the service pack version, it ist not the latest service pack. 
in other words: does the latest fixpack contain the latest liferay service pack?

```
$ ./patching-tool.sh info
Connection timeout. More than 5000ms elapsed.
You can specify the connection timeout by setting the 'connection.timeout' property in the Patching Tool configuration
Cache cannot be updated: connect timed out
You can turn off the cache update from remote server by setting the 'update.cache' property to 'false' in the Patching Tool configuration
Some information will not be available
Loading product and patch information...
Product information:
  * installation type: binary
  * build number: 7010
  * service pack version:
    - available SP version: Not available
    - installable SP version: Not available
  * patching-tool version: 2.0.7
  * time: 2018-07-02 14:10Z
```

Comment: @nicolas-raoul do you have no idea?

Comment: okay, i asked it to liferay and the answer is yes. the latest fix-pack is built on the latest service pack.

Answer (score 0):

If you run 
`./patching-tool.sh info`

It says:

```
Detailed patch list:
  [ -] de-32-7010 :: Currently not installed; Won't be installed: de-53 contains the fixes included in this one :: Built for LIFERAY
  [*I] de-53-7010 :: Installed; Will be installed. :: Built for LIFERAY
```

So we can conclude YES, latest fix-pack contains all previous fix-packs as it should be.